# Strange problem after compiling reactjs boilerplate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Upon first use of the create-react-app boilerplate everything seems to be fine. Prompted with the Edit src/app.js and save to reload, however, after making a change to app.js for example instead of edit src/app.js I change it to testing change; once I click save everything reloads console prints **Compiling... Compiled Successfully!** the browser automatically reloads the content on the page only to find it everything is blank like the default index.html and to add to my confusion further saving of any file within the project tree reloads the pages to the default **Edit src/app.js and save to reload** even though that string no longer exists inside of App.js.

***TLDR:***

- Obtained create-react-app
- create-react-app client
- npm start
- Page shows default
- *edits* App.js changing the display text
- Page stays white after console compiles saying compiled successfully!
- Resaves file causing it to compile twice.
- Once the second compile is done page goes back to default template not displaying new information

**Chrome Browser Console**
Console prints out nothing only telling me to get the react-devtools extension for chrome.

**Terminal**
Compiling...
Compiled successfully!

Comment: Please update the question with the output from the javascript console. Thanks

Comment: Added to question. -thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Post change the screen was white and the console said [get the extension]. I reacreated the app boilerplate multiple times and reloaded the app multiple times.

Default App.js: [image]

---

I would love to have a more scientific solution but this worked for me:

---

I opened the f12 in chrome at the white screen [console said the same stuff] and then reloaded the page. Then, my changes showed. I made changes and saved. Live updates [without refreshing browser manually] started working. 
[image]
I closed the F12 tools and live updates continue to work.
[image]

My *assumption* here is that loading the page with the default F12 tools was enough to get this primed. I do not think it was a waiting thing as I left this overnight after cursing it and walking away. I wish I had a better answer but this worked for me.

Subsequent `[nmp start]`s did **not** require the tools activation to let the page work and show live updates.  I hope this is duplicateable for others.

Loading the react tools extension now.